# How is `class Blog(page)` linked to a specific `Page` in Wagtail CMS GUI?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I do understand how the routing of Wagtail works when a HTTP request arrives.

> 1. **`site`** matching via **`hostname`** and **`port`**
> 2. find the specific **`page`** via **`slug`** settings on Wagtail CMS GUI
> 3. **`serve()`** of that specific page will be called

However, above routing mechanism does not touch the `class` in `models.py` yet. If I have below settings in `models.py` of django which is integrated with Wagtail,

```
class BlogList(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    template = "Post_List.html"
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("intro")
        ]

    subpage_types = [
        "BlogDetail",
    ]

    parent_page_type = [
        "HomePage",
    ]
```

**How do I know this `class BlogList` is linked to which `page` on Wagtail CMS GUI ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlogList` is a subclass of `Page`, meaning that it extends the Page class, with your extra database fields (`intro` in this case).

In the CMS, there is a "Type" column on the page listings (at a URL like `/admin/pages/1/`), which will show you the most-specific class of each page - Unless you specify a name for a page type with `Meta.verbose_name`, it will automatically convert the class name into a sentence - "Blog list" for your example.